# Сумма столбца в графике scatter

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Есть датафрейм с данными о продажах игр. Мне надо сделать точечный график (scatter) по количеству всех игроков за год. Но, так как в один год у разных игр разное количество игроков, получается что-то вот такое [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять как суммировать количество всех игроков за один год.

```
plt.style.use('seaborn')
x=games_sales_df['Year_of_Release']
y=games_sales_df['User_Count']
plt.scatter(x,y,c='green', edgecolor='black')
plt.xlabel('Год')
plt.ylabel('Количество игроков')
```

думал делать что-то по типу:

```
plt.scatter(x,games_sales_df['Year_of_Release']['User_Count'].sum(),c='green', edgecolor='black')
```

Но это было бы слишком уж легко. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо было просто сгруппировать:

```
graph = games_sales_df[["Year_of_Release", "User_Count"]].groupby("Year_of_Release").sum().reset_index()
plt.style.use('seaborn')
x=graph['Year_of_Release']
y=graph['User_Count']
plt.scatter(x,y,c='green', edgecolor='black')
plt.xlabel('Год')
plt.ylabel('Количество игроков')
```